# Print a line from a file under multiple directories

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have the following task:

I have several user directories. In some user directories, there is a folder called `myFolder`. Something like this:

```
/home/usera/a/b/myFolder
/home/userb/a/b/myFolder
/home/userc/a/b/
/home/userd/a/b/myFolder
```

Please note, there is no `myFolder` in the home directory of the `userc`.

Inside `myFolder`, there is a file called `README`. I want to print the second line of the README file with the user name in the console/file.

I am trying with 'sed', but it is giving me output of the first folder. E.g.

```
sed '2!d' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

I can push this command, but it is not giving me the expected output. The ideal output I am looking for is this:

```
usera - v2.2
userb - v2.1
userd - v2.2
```

I am flexible in the way the output is formatted. However, it should print the user name and the second line of the `README` file is a readable way.

Any idea how to achive this?

Comment: Change your command to  sed -ns 2p

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` implementations that support the `nextfile` directive, you can do:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print; nextfile}' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

It would also work with awk implementations that don't support `nextfile`, but would be less efficient as it would read the files fully.

In `sed`, for the `2` address to match on the second line of every file instead of the second line of the whole input, you need the `-s` option of the GNU implementation of `sed`:

```
sed -s '2!d' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

But that also means all the files are read fully, and `sed`, not even GNU `sed` has the equivalent of gawk's `nextfile` or `perl`'s `close ARGV`.

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne '
  if ($. == 2) {print; close ARGV} else {close ARGV if eof}
  ' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

To print the username:

```
awk '
  FNR == 2 {
    split(FILENAME, f, "/")
    print f[3] ": " $0
    nextfile
  }' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

```
perl -ne '
  if ($. == 2) {
    print((split "/", $ARGV)[2] . ": $_");
    close ARGV;
  } else {
    close ARGV if eof;
  }' /home/*/a/b/myFolder/README
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for folder in /home/*/a/b/myFolder; do
  if [ -f "$folder/README" ]; then
    version=$(sed '2!d' "$folder/README")
    username=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $(dirname $folder) ) ) )
    echo "$username - $version"
 fi
done
```

If I were to approach this, I would loop through the common base directory with a wildcard against the username to match all users, test if the path has a `README` file, and if it does, extract the second line from the file, then extract the username from the file path.

Answer (score 0):

With find you cand look for files, and do actiones or execute commands with each one:

```
find /home -path '/home/*/a/b/myFolder/README' -printf '%h - ' -exec sed '2!d' {} \;
```

Comment: That would crawl the whole of `/home` though when it only needs to look for one file in each of the `/home/*` dirs. Note that it would also consider `/home/user/any/amount/of/directories/a/b/myFolder/README`

Comment: It would also give bogus outputs if there were README files with fewer than 2 lines.

Comment: @stéphane-chazelas I do not know if hmhsl wants to crawl the whole /home for searching folders called "myFolder" or not. He say "In some user directories...". It is true that the example has a fixed naming scheme. Regarding to the "bogus outputs", you are right.